# supervisor returns error too many arguments, expected arguments "command"

Tags: laravel, supervisord

I wanna run this command `php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` using `supervisor` but it returns error `too many arguments, expected arguments "command".`.

My `/etc/supervisord.d/conf.d/job-runner.conf` file content:

```
[program:job-runner]
command=php /home/mysite/public_html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=apache
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/mysite/public_html/storage/logs/job-runner.log

[supervisord]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't think you can use `>>` or `2>&` in the command since you already get the `redirect_stderr` option and the `stdout_logfile` option to achieve the same result

Comment: I didn't know the usage of those two lines. THANKS :) DELETE this part ` >> /dev/null 2>&1` and WORKED :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use supervisor for this, supervisor is meant to manage processes not execute scripts.

The command will run, the script will execute and exit, it is likely that supervisor will then auto restart (repeat) this at an uncontrolled tick rate (as fast as the hardware will allow it) that can cause an undesired out of control CPU and memory consumption.

You should use a cron task job as specified in the docs in order to execute schedule task at a controlled rate.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling#introduction

Comment: Thank you very much @MarcNewton. My next question was that why my table getting updated 2 milliseconds after I update the table. By your answer and the reference I got it. Thanks again :)

Comment: @kodfire It would be best to open a new Stack issue explaining your logic issue and provide the code you are running in the schedule task, it is best way of obtaining an answer and someone might reveal a different concept for resolving your problem.